# "Unable to validate data" Exception in my Event Log

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-2.0, iis-8

I had moved my asp.net2 web-forms website to IIS8 base on windows server 2012 and i found in my event log many of the next warning :

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>3</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-01-02T20:44:47.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>2716</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>WIN-6GSFHL7R9M0</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>3005</Data> 
  <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data> 
  <Data>02/01/2014 22:44:47</Data> 
  <Data>02/01/2014 20:44:47</Data> 
  <Data>8ba10465853a48c2a3a0ffc833750679</Data> 
  <Data>7</Data> 
  <Data>1</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>/LM/W3SVC/12/ROOT-2-130331688695275608</Data> 
  <Data>Full</Data> 
  <Data>/</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\</Data> 
  <Data>WIN-6GSFHL7R9M0</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>5216</Data> 
  <Data>w3wp.exe</Data> 
  <Data>WIN-6GSFHL7R9M0\IWPD_6(domain)</Data> 
  <Data>HttpException</Data> 
  <Data>Unable to validate data.</Data> 
  <Data>http://www.domain.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=neQR-vF3_EGwaDvBqhWT03ESuzxtn9v9XFCS44TLY3AvlJgJaiF16o8T3xF9JpxAa4aVdi8FBtTu_aoQwDJm1er-TLBDOoBFHQOWr7lHPFlEhPXZ5Y_wPNlfd8wmC4SLUpFTqQ2&t=635240882914102167</Data> 
  <Data>/ScriptResource.axd</Data> 
  <Data>157.55.35.41</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>False</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>WIN-6GSFHL7R9M0\IWPD_6(domain)</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data>WIN-6GSFHL7R9M0\IWPD_6(domain)</Data> 
  <Data>False</Data> 
  <Data>at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean signData) at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, IVType ivType, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptStringWithIV(String s, IVType ivType) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s)</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**I have tried the following things :**

- Use of specifying machine key
- Add renderAllHiddenFieldsAtTopOfForm="true"
- I saw many posts suggesting EnableViewStateMAC=false, but it's sound stupid and dangers

Is this exception dangers? what i'm missing ?

Comment: Did you find only _one_ of these? Or does it happen on every request? That would help you decide how important it is.

Comment: More important is the fact that you're getting unhandled exceptions and don't know about it. Look into [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398933.ASPX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it.

The most likely explanation is that a search crawler / indexer has cached the old URLs and is checking them again to make sure they're still valid. Since ScriptResource.axd returns 404 for these now-incorrect URLs, the search crawler will eventually flush them from its cache, and over time you'll see these errors disappear.